# How to insert multi-line output of AWK to Array in UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I made the following work on Linux (RHEL 6.x/7.x), however, there are Unix servers too running HP-UX (B.11.23/B.11.31).

My target isn't to make the same block to work for both envs, I can enforce them to run separately based on OS. But need to perform the following.

Please help me out finding an easy way to do the following on Unix.

#

```
ABC="/u01/app/oracle /u02/app/oracle /u03/app/oracle"

array=($(echo $ABC | awk -F' ' '{for (i = 0; ++i <= NF;) print $i}'))

for i in "${array[@]}"; do echo $i; done
```

#

O/P ::

```
/u01/app/oracle
/u02/app/oracle
/u03/app/oracle
```

#

I want to get the same thing above done in Unix too. Problem is, there is no way I could find how to insert multiline awk output into an array at one shot like that is possible in RHEL.

Comment: Why don't you just say `ABC=(/u01/app/oracle /u02/app/oracle /u03/app/oracle)`?

Comment: And what shell do the HP-UX systems have?

Comment: I'm basically getting directories used by database for existing datafiles. Which comes with a space in between instead of a newline. ABC=sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<EOF set feed off set heading off set feedback off select distinct(substr(file_name,1,instr(file_name,'/', -1, 1))) from dba_data_files; exit EOF So it is pretty much formatted that way with above approach. I'm using korn shell (ksh)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do this, good thing it works both with Linux and Unix.

```
countArr=0
for i in $ABC; do array[$countArr]=$i; countArr=$((countArr+1)); done
for i in "${array[@]}"; do echo $i; done
```